# How to run executable jar file without high dpi scaling?

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar, filesize, highdpi

I am having a problem with my java system,  I tried to run my project in executable jar file but the size from layout, or text is getting bigger, i believed it is because of high dpi scale from windows,  is there anyway to disable high dpi scale from my sytem because the executable jar file doesnt have property to turn off dpi scaling,  and also i already tried on java.exe or javaw.exe to disable dpi scaling but still doesnt work. If i tried to change windows dpi scaling to 100% my system goes back to its original size, but the other application/program turns to smaller. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

you can try launching your java application with the following argument:

```
-Dsun.java2d.ddscale=false
```

Another possible solution can be to modify the scale factor, but this is not working on all JVM versions... you can give it a try if the previous does not work:

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=PUT_FLOAT_VALUE_HERE
```

In my case this solved the same problem I was facing :)

Comment: In my case, the `uiScale` parameter does not seem to work with floating values. It only works with integers like `1`, `2`, `3` etc. I am on Kubuntu with OpenJDK 14. I wonder why.